# Android send command to serial port and wait for specific response

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, serial-port, queue

My application connects to a specific hardware over a serial port. I send binary data commands while each command includes specific Opcode. 
I receive from the hardware the same Opcode or another in return. 
To do this, I have a queue of commands in thread, dedicated to send the data.Another thread dedicated to reading and handling all incoming replies and put it in another queue.

Now, lets say I need to send a command with opcode 1 and then I want to wait for the hardware to reply me with opcode 1(there might be different data between sending and receiving) , however this is going to be a little tricky cause there might be some other messages being received by my application, commands with opcodes 2 or 3 and so on, and I need to handle them properly without waiting to command with opcode 1. If I wait too long to command with opcode 1 I need to be informed.

1. Do I need to open a thread timer for each command, and after amount of time call back a listener?
2. Is there a design pattern and implementation for this kind?

I looked for some posts here and I don't think I can stop my search
Look at this:
[c# wait for an echo on serial port, check it, and have a timout on the wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16007313/c-sharp-wait-for-an-echo-on-serial-port-check-it-and-have-a-timout-on-the-wait)?
[Providing Asynchronous Serial Port Communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916830/providing-asynchronous-serial-port-communication)?

Can anyone give me some advice?
Thanks!